# JQuery lightbox showing all images in page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, lightbox

I have to use a JQuery lightbox in my application.

My application has a result page which shows results of a query in the form of table for each result. Each such table has some thumbnail images.

While clicking on the thumbnail, the lightbox opens up listing all the thumbnails of all the the results.

I want the thumbnails of the selected table only to be listed in the lightbox.

This is how I have implemented it:

```
<tr>
<td>
<div id="thumbnails"> 
<ul class="clearfix"> 
<?php 
if($img2!=null){ 
echo '<li><a href='.$img2.'><img src='.$img2.' alt="turntable" height="50" width="50" style="display:inline;"></a></li>';
} 
if($img3!=null)
{ 
echo '<li><a href='.$img3.'><img src='.$img3.' alt="turntable" height="50" width="50" style="display:inline;"></a></li>';
} 
?> 
</ul> </div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() 
{ 
$('#thumbnails a').lightBox(); 
});
</div></div></td></tr>
```

Comment: add a little bit of code which may helpful to understand

Comment: Try editing your answer and Post the code there not in the comments